# Do Star Trek fonts exist for LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

I've been looking for Star Trek fonts or symbols for LaTeX lately, but unfortunately I couldn't find any. Do any of you know if there is a Star Trek font or character set?

Comment: With LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX you can use almost any font. Can you link to an existing Star Trek font (whatever it is ;-) )?

Comment: Have you tried googling "star trek font"?

Comment: @ Mico Yes I did, but I haven't found one to use with LaTeX.

Comment: @ Rmano For example, how about the TNG title on this page: 
http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/fonts/index.html
How would you include it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`startrek` is an [existing](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fundus/startrek/startrek.pdf) package in `LaTeX` but I don't know how it works.

In the introducion there is written:

*This package provides a means to use some PostScript fonts with LATEX. The fonts
are similar to some fonts used in the context of the startrek films.
The PostScript fonts are not contained in the distribution but have to be a got
separately*.

Here there is a [file1](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fundus/startrek/startrek.dtx) `.dtx` and [file2](https://www.sys.kth.se/docs/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fundus/startrek.sty) `.sty` here there are the fonts (I think) - http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.cs.vu.nl/pub/minix/distfiles/local/3.3.0/:

- http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.cs.vu.nl/pub/minix/distfiles/local/3.3.0/PS_Font_Trek_Arrowcaps.zip
- http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.cs.vu.nl/pub/minix/distfiles/local/3.3.0/PS_Font_Trek_Arrowheads.zip
- http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.cs.vu.nl/pub/minix/distfiles/local/3.3.0/Star_Trek.tar.gz

Comment: @ Sebastiano Molte grazie! I tried to use the fonts this morning but had the famous .sty not found problem. Saluti da Berlino, Fabio.

Comment: @Fab2 Hi, ahhah..I'm very happy to help you. I have done a mistake. You have .dtx and .sty files to save with the extension .dtx and .sty. My best regards....from East Sicily....:-) I'm not very expert....but an hunter ahahah